# How to confirm whether I need a full Application Server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, application-server

We have a product that runs as a war file in WildFly. We want to know whether it will run in a simple servlet container like Tomcat as well. Is there a way to confirm this, e.g. by code analysis?

In the past the code did depend on Java EE features, but much of this has been replaced with Spring components, so now we want to know whether we still need the full EE stack.

We could just run the war file in Tomcat, but is there a possibility that some errors (due to missing Java EE bindings) will not pop up at boot time, but only later (e.g. when scheduled background processes run)?

Comment: put it in the tomcat and run it, U will see, And test all points.

Answer (score 0):

If you have EE Beans such as MDB, SLSB I believe you'll need the full application server.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do similar thing recently. For that I had deployed and kept on changing things for which I was getting error.
 
If you are not using below features then you can try switching to Tomcat

- JMS
- Flexible and strong clustering
- JTA support for transaction management (can be added externally in tomcat using Bitronix/Atomikos)
- Advanced security features, etc.